# React Native Multiline ReturnKeyType Bug

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, multiline

I've made a TextInput where `multiline={true}` . I wanted to stop the user from being able to enter a newline themselves, so I set `returnKeyType={'done'}`. However, the `returnKeyType` prop seems to be nonfunctional when the `multiline` prop is true. Is there a work around for this, or will I just have to wait until they patch this? I'm using an android phone and am on react-native version 0.44.0.

Answer (score 11):

try to set `blurOnSubmit` aside from `returnKeyType={'done'}` and `multiline`

Comment: Do you happen to know why is this? Is it in the documentation?